# npm ERR! Could not install from as it does not contain a package.json file angular firebase functions

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

I am using **"firebase-functions": "^3.6.0"**, **"firebase-tools": "^8.0.0"** to deploy my **Angular: 10.0.14** app. All was working fine until I decided to move some components into a library created using the command `ng generate library` and made the package a submodule in my project under `./projects/my-lib`

I build the lib using `ng build my-lib`

Then in my `package.json` installed the lib from file

`"my-lib": "file:dist/my-lib"`

I installed the package locally and it works fine when I test it locally but deploying using **ng deploy** raised the error

`npm ERR! Could not install from "dist/mce-lib" as it does not contain a package.json file.`

I have tried a couple of solutions I found online, but no luck yet

Answer (score 9):

Try this

First, remove node_modules and package-lock.json file

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

Then, clean cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And last re-install modules

```
npm i
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, most of the time this is caused by the package-lock.json file which contains incompatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the library by using

```
  ng generate library <your lib name>
```

This will setup your lib with the necessary files so that you can add it as a dependency.

Otherwise, if you want to do this manually it'll require more work.

**UPDATE:**

To be able to use the lib above locally without publishing you will need to do the following

From withing your app directory for which you generated the lib, go into ./projects/ as it was generated by the lib command above. Then run the following build command

```
  ng build <your lib name> --prod
```

The prod tag is optional but it helps to run your code in that flag so that it is the closest to what it will look like once you publish

Then go back to your app root folder and install the application by referencing the dist folder. The build command above should have added your lib as its own folder withing dist

```
  npm install ./dist/<your lib name>
```

**NOTE:** All of this is for dev testing purposes. Ideally, you will want to publish your lib to npmjs or github packages first and then install it properly in your app before you deploy your app to production

**Another way of locally:**  though the use of npm link

```
   cd ./dist/<your lib name>
   npm link
```

Then going back to root folder of app, you should be able to run the installation as such

```
  npm link <your lib name>
```

This creates a local link to your library in your app for testing purposes that doesn't modify your package.json file as installing the directory directly does. Once you are done, always make sure to run unlink

```
 npm unlink <your lib name>
```

And withing your ./dist/

```
 npm unlink
```

Comment: You should add what you have tried to avoid confusion then...

Comment: @theTypan I think you're probably missing some steps. Check out above update as I have provided step by step on how I have done this in the past

Comment: @EdwardRomero Thanks again..I have tried your steps but it did not work

Comment: @theTypan that's very odd. Can you update the question above with your apps directory structure. That's the only other thing that I can think is messed up when creating your lib, that causes the steps above to not worked properly. The idea is for us to be able to see your app, and the location of the lib you created to make sure your repo is setup properly

Comment: @EdwardRomero I posted my own answer, Thanks a lot...I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of trying to figure out how to solve this, I came across these resources that helped me to resolve the issue:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies#including_local_nodejs_modules_as_part_of_your_deployment_package

> Note: The Firebase CLI ignores the local node_modules folder when deploying your function.

[Firebase Functions local "file:" dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458795/firebase-functions-local-file-dependencies)

So even if the app was working locally, the `node_modules` isn't deployed

Since I had installed python packages from git before, I thought why not make use of this? I am using Gitlab and this answer really helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/50314604/3247914

I got it working by installing my package from git